# How to tell a Vue app that it will be located in a sub folder and get image path replaced accordingly?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

My vue app is located in a sub folder and accessible via a URL like this :

domain.com/myapp/

In my component template, I add to do :

```
<img :src= "base_path + '/img/undraw_profile.svg'">
```

where base_path is included in an imported file.

Is there a better way? In a config file or something ?

So when the app is built by vite all URLs in templates are transformed from "img/a.jpg" to "/myapp/img/a.jpg" ?

I know that with vue-cli some people use a env.process variable but I use vue3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vite, have a look at the `base` property in vite.config.js: https://vite-plugin-ssr.com/base-url

```
// vite.config.js
export default {
  base: '/some-base/'
}
```

For assets, have a look at https://vite-plugin-ssr.com/base-url#baseassets

```
// vite.config.js

import { ssr } from 'vite-plugin-ssr/plugin'

export default {
  plugins: [
    ssr({
      baseAssets: 'https://cdn.example.org/my-website-assets/'
    })
  ]
}
```

For Vue CLI, have a look at the `publicPath`: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath

Give it a go.

Comment: I did it (base option). It replace router link, but not the path of assets.

Comment: Have you tried `baseAssets`? https://vite-plugin-ssr.com/base-url#baseassets (added to the answer as well)